# Why Can't I Run Valgrind on Another User's Executable?

Tags: permissions, valgrind

I want to run Valgrind on an executable built by another user on the same system. When I do this, I do not receive line numbers for errors, which nearly defeats the purpose. Instead, I get errors which look like the executable was built without a symbol table, or like I cannot read the files.

Things I have checked:

- The running user has read permission on all the source files, and the directories they are in files.
- running with sudo -u running_user doesn't work, but, without recompiling, running with root permissions does work.

What permissions does Valgrind need in order to operate? Is this error caused by something other than permissions?

Comment: Is the executable compiled with the debugging (`-g`) flag?

Comment: @solvingPuzzles Yes, that's why I checked whether or not it works when I run it as root. When I say it "works", I mean I get line numbers as usual.

Comment: Work around, in case this doesn't get a proper answer: I ended up just checking out a clean version of the source under the running_user, and running valgrind there. Still want to know why it doesn't work with sudo -u.